# Go connecting to ssh results in handshake failed

Tags: go, ssh

currently I am trying to connect to ssh with golang.
I enabled the PasswordAuthentication on the server and testet it by conecting via terminal this
worked like a charm no problems at all. The final goal ist to connect to a MySQL DB via ssh tunnel.

```
    sshConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: os.Getenv("SSH_USER"),
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password(""),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }

    conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "", sshConfig)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

The credentials were loaded via env vars and they also worked.

But the ssh.Dial funtion threw allways follwing error:

```
ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none password], no supported methods remain
```

1. I checked /etc/ssh/sshd_config
2. I tried to use the same authentication method via the terminal and it worked
3. I checked the credentials

Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you check in `sshd_config`? Is password auth actually enabled? The server logs will have the reason auth failed.

Comment: @JimB password auth is enabeld. The logs are follwing: Failed passworf for root from IP port PORT ssh2. Connection closed by authentication user root IP port PORT [preatuh]